# Laws of electrolysis and quantisation of charge relation

Tags: electrochemistry

> The quantisation of charge was first suggested by the experimental laws of electrolysis discovered by Faraday

I think about it a lot but could not find any relation, as the number of electrons involved is too large in electrolysis that the charge can be assumed to be continuous and discrete nature is negligible.

How did Faraday first suggested quantisation by this non microscopic process (electrolysis)?

Comment: Did you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_laws_of_electrolysis? It's the number of  chemical valence electrons that is discrete, which is different for different metals. Some go into (or come out of) solution using one electron, others need two or three.

Comment: @CuriousOne      so discrete nature of valence electrons suggested quantisation of charge?

Comment: Yes. You are correct that one can't measure a single electron that way, but it's easy to distinguish 1 mole of electrons from 2 mole of electrons.